# The need for index.html

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I'm pretty new to using Jekyll, and I just had a question in regards to the need of the `index.html` file. Currently, all that file has inside is this:

```
---
layout:default
---
```

It seems all it's doing is calling the `default.html` template which I've created, and nothing else.

What's the need for this file, other than serving as a landing page for the website, which calls another template? Is it worth having any other code on this page?

Comment: the actual content of your index page should stay here and referenced in the layout with ``{{ content }}`` variable, not in the layout (since the same layout could be reused for other pages)

Comment: Your index page is supposed to have content. Have a look at the Jekyll's default index.html, it contains a list of post.

You definitely must put content in your index page.

Answer (score 0):

You need it to call a template. Instead of having two pages you can just make index.html your template. No matter what, the page needs to be there for reference.